# UITabBarController never calls initWithNibName on individual tabs?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Is it true that `UITabBarController` never calls `initWithNibName` on its child views (individual tabs)?  Or have I just set my app up in a really screwed-up way?

My MainWindow.xib looks like this in interface builder:
[tab bar in interface builder http://web.mit.edu/keone/Public/tabbar.png](http://web.mit.edu/keone/Public/tabbar.png)

Note that the Window is completely blank while all the action happens in the Tab Bar Controller.

My app delegate calls `[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and once that happens we're off to the races!

But when I put breakpoints on the `init`, `initWithNibName:`, and `initWithNibName:bundle:` methods in any of my individual controllers (which are listed in Interface Builder as children of the tabs, as the image above shows), nothing catches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't call `initWithNibName:`, they call `initWithCoder:` -- `initWithNibName:` is only called when you programmatically instantiate a class and hand it a xib file to define its subviews from.

(Updated: I remembered wrong, `initWithNibName:` is never called unless one makes the call oneself.)

Comment: aha.  `initWithCoder` indeed catches.  By the way, my child views *are* defined in nibs (e.g. some of the elements never get initialized in code, only by the device reading the associated nib file).  So that means `initWithNibName:` only gets called for top-level type things?

Comment: Yes, and actually my answer is incorrect -- they all get `initWithCoder:` -- will update in a sec.

Comment: it was sending me nuts! you are my today hero :)